# Make child of scrollview 1/3 size

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have this:
[image]

my problem is that i have a Linearlayout wrapper with a scrollview and a Linearlayout inside.. i want every item to be 1/3 of the scrollviews height no matter how many items i put into it..

When i add items to the Linearlayout it is linearlayouts, if i add 3 'items' it is almost fine.. but if i add 8 items, they are all quite small and scrollable. This is what i want, but i want them to have the height of 1/3 of the scrollview/linearlayout.

i want it to align so its as big as the buttons in the 2nd layout i have.

i just cant seems to make it right, hope its just a simple solution i have refused to see.

my code so far:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="75">
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
                    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/coats"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="75">

                 </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is my way of adding 'children' to the layout wrapped by the scrollview

```
LinearLayout w0 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout w1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        ImageView w2 = new ImageView(this);
        TextView w3 = new TextView(this);
        TextView w4 = new TextView(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 25);
        params.setMargins(pixelToDp(0),pixelToDp(5),pixelToDp(0),pixelToDp(5));
        w0.setLayoutParams(params);
        w0.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        w0.setClickable(true);

        w0.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 100, 100, 100));
        w0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int i = 0; i < LLCoats.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View vv = LLCoats.getChildAt(i);
                    vv.setSelected(false);
                    vv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 100, 100, 100));
                }
                LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout)LLCoats.getChildAt(i);
                TextView TV = (TextView)LL.getChildAt(1);
                TV.requestFocus();

                if(TV.getError() != null)
                {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), ""+TV.getError(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }



                v.setSelected(true);
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,255));
            }
        });

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2);
        w1.setLayoutParams(params2);
        w1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        w1.setClickable(false);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);
        w2.setLayoutParams(params3);
        w2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);      

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);
        w3.setLayoutParams(params4);
        w3.setTextSize(25f);
        w3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        w3.setClickable(false);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);
        w4.setLayoutParams(params5);
        w4.setTextSize(45f);
        w4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        w4.setClickable(false);

        w1.addView(w2);
        w1.addView(w3);

        w0.addView(w1);
        w0.addView(w4);

        LLCoats.addView(w0);
```

UPDATE!:

Now its getting really weird, as i have found a way to calculate the height and add it with:

```
DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, pixelToDp((int)(display.heightPixels* .8 * 0.25)));
```

This works really well on my PI64 and a ASUS tablet, but my phone makes the height 100% the same as the scrollview, how is happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it works like this, getting the screen size *.8 because the screen is used as a popup and then 0.25 as items are 1/4 of the screen and in the end -10 for my margins

```
DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();        

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(display.heightPixels* .8 * 0.25 - pixelToDp(10)));       

        params.setMargins(pixelToDp(0),pixelToDp(5),pixelToDp(0),pixelToDp(5));
```